# Django TemplateDoesNotExist problem while DIR is correctly set

Tags: python, django

I was running this Django project perfectly previously using Python3.7.2 and Django 2.1.5, recently I installed Anaconda3 and changed the interpreter to the Python3.7.1 in it. After reinstalling Django, when I ran the project the TemplateDoesNotExist exception showed up. My OS is Windows 10.

My DIRS is set as below:

```
TDIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Templates/').replace('\\', '/')
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TDIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This note is on the error page:

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\welcomePage.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\welcomePage.html (Source does not exist)
```

It seems that Django search the Anaconda path for templates instead of the customized path, but I can see on the error page that it was correctly set. This is what the error page shows:

```
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['D:/IgnorazWork/SUDoc/SUDoc/Templates/'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
```

And`'D:/IgnorazWork/SUDoc/SUDoc/Templates/'`is exactly where I put the templates. How does this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates/',],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Note - Make sure that your folder name are exactly same `Template\` and `template\` are different

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. And I have already checked my folder name.